# What is getConfigData?

Tags: magento

What is **getConfigData**? and diff between getConfigData and getStoreConfigData in Magento.

```
$this->getConfigData('shippingspecificcountry', $store_id);
```

I tried with my current store id and 0, both gives empty array.

Can anyone explain about the above method.

Comment: `grep -iR 'function getConfigData(' ./app/code/core|wc -l`. So there seem to be 13 definitions of the method in the core of magento, 4 more in enterprise, Which one are you talking about ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question could use a little more context -- lacking that.

The `Mage::getStoreConfig` method is a static method on the global `Mage` class, and provides access to configuration values stored in Magento's Configuration tree.  Magento's configuration tree is created by

1. Loading all XML files in `app/etc/*.xml`
2. Loading all XML files from `app/etc/modules/*.xml'
3. Merging all the `config.xml` files from the active modules
4. Merging in any values set in `core_config_data` (via `System -> Configuration` in the admin)

Because Magento's configuration is so big, many module developers add methods like `getConfigData` or `getConfig` to make fetching specific configuration values easy.  For example, consider this oversimplified example

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('foo/baz/bar')
```

vs.

```
$this->getConfig('bar');

....
public function getConfigData($key)
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('foo/baz/' . $bar);
}
```

The second allows a client programmer more concise code.

You can see an example of this in the base class for Magento's [various shipping carriers](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php#L95)

```
public function getConfigData($field)
{
    if (empty($this->_code)) {
        return false;
    }
    $path = 'carriers/'.$this->_code.'/'.$field;
    return Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $this->getStore());
}
```

Here the `getConfigData` method will automatically look for the configuration key in the `carriers` node -- using the carrier's `_code` as a sub-node, and checking the instantiated carrier object for a store code.

The `getConfigData` method will behave differently depending on which class/object you're using, but hopefully that's enough to get you pointed in the right direction.